# I want to send data into many Table from one FORM but my selected table not others

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to in programming. I want to send data into multiple tables by using one FORM but not every table just my selected table will be updated with data.
It's similar to have an option when I select an option it will send only this table not others, I don't know is it a right method or wrong please help me...

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="data-store text-center">
            <?php
                add_part('admin-menu.php');
            ?>
            <?php
                if(!empty($_POST)){
                    $title=$_POST['title'];
                    $sel_data='sel_data';
                    if($sel_data == 1){
                        $insert="INSERT INTO `database`.`gfx` (`gfx_id`, `gfx_title`) VALUES (NULL, '$title');";
                        if(mysqli_query($con,$insert)){
                            echo "Product has been uploaded";
                        }

                    }else{
                        echo "Failed to store data";
                    }

                    if($sel_data == 2){
                        $insert="INSERT INTO `database`.`gfx` (`gfx_id`, `gfx_title`) VALUES (NULL, '$title');";
                        if(mysqli_query($con,$insert)){
                            echo "Product has been uploaded";
                        }

                    }else{
                        echo "Failed to store data";
                    }



                }
            ?>

            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div>
                    <label for="title"></label>
                    <input name="title" id="title" type="text" placeholder="post title"/> 
                </div>

                <select name="sel_data" id="">
                    <option name="" >Select one</option>
                    <option name="table1" value="1">Option 1</option>
                    <option name="table2" value="2">Option 2</option>
                    <option name="table3" value="3">Option 3</option>
                </select>

                <input type="submit" value="submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: how are you getting the option? from where?

Comment: From select tag options

Comment: but what i can see is you are storing a string sel data in $sel_data. how can you match $sel_data==1 if its a string?

Comment: it would be great if you tell me how to send data to multiple database table from one FORM but not send every table at a time only the table I want by setting any functionality, is it possible?

Comment: ok i am telling you the answer, but make sure $sel_data gets integer value and not string value like $sel_data=1 or 2, i am just posting your php loop rest you do by yourself

Comment: at a time you will save the data to multiple table or only single table because your `<select>` is not `multiselect` its only single select

Answer (score 1):

Select tables from your database using

" SELECT table_name
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema =  'your_database_name'
  "

use resulted array for generating options using foreach.
then instead of giving integer value for options, you should give name of table as value. after than you can change code as

```
        <?php
            if(!empty($_POST)){
                $title = $_POST['title'];
                $sel_data = $_POST['sel_data'];
                $insert="INSERT INTO `database`.`.$sel_data.` (`gfx_id`, `gfx_title`) VALUES (NULL, '$title');";
                if(mysqli_query($con,$insert)){
                  echo "Product has been uploaded";
                }else{
                  echo "Failed to store data";
                }
             }
        ?>
```

By using above code entered title will be inserted into selected table only.

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize your code like this if all the table having the same structure.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $sel_data = $_POST['sel_data'];
    if (!empty($sel_data)) {
        $insert = "INSERT INTO $sel_data.`gfx` (`gfx_id`, `gfx_title`) VALUES (NULL, '$title');";
        if (mysqli_query($con, $insert)) {
            echo "Product has been uploaded";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Failed to store data";
    }
}
?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="data-store text-center">
<?php
add_part('admin-menu.php');
?>           

        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div>
                <label for="title"></label>
                <input name="title" id="title" type="text" placeholder="post title"/> 
            </div>

            <select name="sel_data" id="">
                <option  value="" >Select one</option>
                <option  value="table1">Option 1</option>
                <option  value="table2">Option 2</option>
                <option  value="table3">Option 3</option>
            </select>

            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use $sel_data =$_POST['sel_data'] instead of $sel_data ='sel_data';

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**
       hey have you tried elseif? and also i think the only wrong thing was your structure

```
    <?php
                    if(!empty($_POST)){
                        $title=$_POST['title'];
                        $sel_data=$_POST['sel_data']; // you need to call the value of the select
                        if($sel_data == 1){
                            $insert="INSERT INTO `database`.`gfx` (`gfx_id`, `gfx_title`) VALUES (NULL, '$title');";
                              if(mysqli_query($con,$insert)){
                                echo "Product has been uploaded";
                                }
                                else{
                                  echo "Failed to store data";
                            }
                        }


                        elseif($sel_data == 2){
                            $insert="INSERT INTO `database`.`gfx` (`gfx_id`, `gfx_title`) VALUES (NULL, '$title');";   
                            if(mysqli_query($con,$insert)){
                                echo "Product has been uploaded";
                            }
                            else{
                            echo "Failed to store data";
                              }
                            }

                         elseif($sel_data == 3){
                            $insert="INSERT INTO `database`.`gfx` (`gfx_id`, `gfx_title`) VALUES (NULL, '$title');";   
                             if(mysqli_query($con,$insert)){
                                echo "Product has been uploaded";
                            }
                            else{
                            echo "Failed to store data";
                                }
                            }

                        else {
                            echo"failed";
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: thanks man its working but the Query should be inside the condition as it my table is differnt from one another

Comment: can you maybe check me if it works or maybe vote up thanks :)